# WordPress randomly shows 404 errors

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, urls, 404-error

I am maintaining a wordpress website developed by someone else which is not available. The problem is that it randomly shows 404 template page and when refreshing the page again it shows the page. Here are the list of works I did to solve the problem, but had no success yet:

- Deactivating all plugins.
- Flushing rewrite rules with `rewrite_flush_rules()` function
- Disabling cache
- Using a fresh `.htaccess` file that I got from WordPress codex page
- Also I tried to use some debugging plugins, but couldn't figure out anything from the huge amount of data they were showing.

None of the above worked.

Also I read in some articles that heavy (or not properly?) usage of custom post types may cause this problem, and there are around 15 custom post types being used on the website. But I am not sure where to look for the problem.

The only things that I am sure so far are:

- The problem is not related to plugins, as I deactivated all of them and the problem continued to show up
- It is a wordpress related problem rather than web server. As It shows the 404 template and after refreshing the page the 404 error goes away.

I would appreciate your response if you could suggest any method to find the reason of the problem.

Comment: did you cleared your cache after deactivating the plugins? if not then do & check, i faced similar problem before and a plugin was the culprit.

Comment: What does the server log say? And what does `rewrite_flush_rules()` do?

Comment: @Arsalan & Max Thank you. Im currently on mobile and will check for those soon.